# Facebook orkut style date in android application

Tags: android, date

In my application I am showing a list of posts with its creator name, text of post and post date.

I want to show date in the format which is used in facebook or orkut like if a post is added before 3 sec then I want to show date as "added 3 sec ago"

Can any one please guide me how to achieve this in android.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library.